# Adding 'Read More' link in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have trying to `excerpt` some text and add `Read More` link. So far I was able to cut the text and add `Read More` but now I can to make few lines between text and read more link.

Here is how I truncated the text

```
{{ str_limit($product['description_small'], $limit = 250, $end = ' Read More') }}
```

How can I put this `$end = ' Read More'` few lines under the text and to make it link?

Laravel 4 + blade template

Comment: `$end = '<br><br>  Read More';`

Comment: Thank's.. it's so obvious.. but how to make it link now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing you can do is create your own function to create the `excerpt` and add the `Read More` link.

First of all in your `composer.json` file, in the `autolaod` section add a `files` array:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Now in your `app/` folder create the `helpers.php` file.

Then add in `app\start\global.php`: ( **NB: this is required only for Laravel 4** )

```
// at the bottom of the file
require app_path().'/helpers.php';
```

Then:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

In this way Laravel will load the file for you.

Now in this file you can create your onw function to manage the `excerpt`:

```
<?php

if( ! function_exists('createExcerptAndLink')){

    function createExcerptAndLink($text, $limit, $url, $readMoreText = 'Read More') {

        $end = "<br><br><a href=\"$url\">$readMoreText</a>";

        return str_limit($text, $limit, $end);
    }

}
```

Now in every view you can use your new helper:

```
{{ createExcerptAndLink($product['description_small'], 250, "http://www.google.it", 'Read more here.') }}
```

Comment: I can't use composer on this machine

Comment: Not even on your development machine?

Comment: Yes. I've tried something like `<a href="{{ URL::to('/readmore/' . $product['product_id']) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>`